# Fallback method not being called by @HystrixCommand annotation

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-netflix, hystrix

fallback method mentioned in @HystrixCommand is not being called in case a downstream service is down. I am using spring boot version 3.
I am not sure what I am missing here.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.practice</groupId>
    <artifactId>movie-catalog-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>movie-catalog-service</name>
    <description>Movie Catalog Service</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.4</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableHystrix
public class MovieCatalogServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MovieCatalogServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

```
@HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "getFallbackCatalog")
    public List<CatalogItem> getCatalog(String userId) {

        UserRating userRating = restTemplate.getForObject("http://ratings-data-service/ratingsdata/user/{userId}",
                UserRating.class, userId);

        return userRating.getRatings().stream().map(rating -> {
            Map<String, String> param = new HashMap<>();
            param.put("movieId", rating.getMovieId());
            
            Movie movie = restTemplate.getForObject("http://movie-info-service/movies/{movieId}", Movie.class,
                    rating.getMovieId());
            return new CatalogItem(movie.getName(), "description", rating.getRating());
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

//Fall back method

```
    private List<CatalogItem> getFallbackCatalog(@PathVariable("userId") String userId){
        return Arrays.asList(new CatalogItem("No movie", "", 0));
    }
```

If movie-info-service is down, call should come to getFallbackCatalog instead it is throwing error saying movie-info-service is not available.